# Boost Python Python return value to C++ program

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I have a python embedding in C++ where C++ calls a function in python and should be returned a value. Here is my python code:

```
def predict(window, g_slope, g_compliance):
    ps = model.predict_on_batch(
        x=np.asarray([window])
    )

    p_slopes = ps[0]
    p_compliances = ps[1]
    p_slopes = np.reshape(p_slopes, (np.shape(p_slopes)[1],))
    p_compliances = np.reshape(p_compliances, (np.shape(p_compliances)[1],))
    p_slope = p_slopes[-1]
    p_compliance = p_compliances[-1]

    n_slope = standardize_data(g_slope, means['GROUND_SLOPE'], variances['GROUND_SLOPE'])
    n_compliance = standardize_data(g_compliance, means['GROUND_STIFFNESS'], variances['GROUND_STIFFNESS'])

    #print('p_compliance: {0}, n_compliance: {1}, p_slope: {2}, n_slope: {3} '.format(str(p_compliance), str(n_compliance), str(n_slope), str(p_slope)))

    return(p_slope, n_slope, p_compliance, n_compliance)
```

It returns the tuple that I would like to receive in my C++ program.
My C++ program calls the function like this:

```
void ContactLearningApp::PythonWorkerThread() {

    bp::object f = m_interface.attr("predict_on_data");

    printf("Start Python thread. \n");

    while (true) {
        //printf("Inside while loop and waiting. \n");
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m_mutex);
        while (m_data.size() <= 0) {
            m_NotEmptyCV.wait(ul);
        }
        Data dat = m_data.back();
        m_data.pop_back();

        ul.unlock();

        m_pydata_ptr py_ptr(new PyData);

        py_ptr->InitWithData(dat);
        try {
            bp::tuple results = bp::extract<bp::tuple>(f(bp::ptr(py_ptr.get())));
            printf("p_slope: %f, n_slope: %f, p_compliance: %f, n_compliance %f \n", results[0], results[1], results[2], results[3]);
        }
        catch (const bp::error_already_set &import) {
            // Parse and output the exception
            std::string perror_str = parse_python_exception();
            std::cout << "Error in Python: " << perror_str << std::endl;
        }
    }

}
```

I'm trying to extract the tuple returned from Python but I get the following error message:

```
Expecting an object of type tuple; got an object of type NoneType instead.
```

I know that it isn't none since I am able to access each of the values in the tuple correctly. What is the correct way of extracting the tuple?

Answer (score 0):

`boost::python::object` supports `operator[]` which allows to access sequence (list, tuple etc) elements by index. This means that you don't need to cast an `object` returned from your function into a `tuple`, you can access its elements directly:

```
bp::object func = bp::import("my_module").attr("my_func");
bp::object foo = func();
bp::object bar = foo[0];
```

If a returned python object does not support by index access, an exception will be thrown. Note that you may still need to cast sequence elements extracted by index into respective C++ types.

And usually you can pass arguments to function objects from C++ "as is", without messing with raw `PyObject*` pointers. Boost.Python does necessary conversions in most cases.

Comment: I tried to extract the value from the object like this:  `bp::extract<double>(results[0])` But it gave me a `NoneType object is not subscriptable` error.

Comment: Ignore above. But, I tried to extract the value from the object like this:  `bp::extract<double>(results[0])` But it gives me a value of 0.00000, which is contrary to what my python script is printing.